# Need help connecting MSSQL via Soci

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc, soci

Today I was thought of creating a C++ app that connects to MS SQL server and do functions such as retrieving records and execute SPROCs, Then I found this `Soci`, a C++ library which helps our app to talk with DB, and I also found there is no specific backend-option in Soci for MSSQL unlike it has for Oracle and others, looks like, we could only talk to mssql via ODBC. however, I have been searching for a proper document/manual/reference which would give me a step by step instructions for connecting to MSSQL via `soci`, I wandered around Soci's mother-site but nothing I could find for MSSQL.
(I have seen this

`backend_factory const& backEnd = odbc; session sql(backEnd, "filedsn=c:\\my.dsn");`

But, my DB's are hosted in a separate server, so, it would be hellpful if someone could shed some light on this:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ODBC` to connect to sql server with `Soci` using a connection string like the following:

```
"DRIVER=libtdsodbc.so;SERVER=MYSERVER;PORT=1433;DATABASE=my_database_name;UID=username;PWD=password"
```

With the `Session` creation function (using [odbc as per the Soci documentation](http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/release/4.0/backends/odbc/)).

Where:

- `MYSERVER` is the address / name of the server you want to connect to.
- `1433` is the default port for sqlServer, this may be different in your case.
- `my_database_name` is the name of the database you are trying to access

This should then be using [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) on top of the ODBC driver.
The authentication is interesting, by default FreeTDS will use sql authentication, [unless there is a backslash in the user name](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/domains.html) then it will use Windows Domain Logon for authentication EG: `"DOMAIN\username"`

Also interesting is the [FreeTDS connection string parameters.](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/OdbcConnAttr.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Fantastic,Very helpful answer.